# Chat Application using Asp.net giving Database errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ajax, linq-to-sql

I am making a Chat Application in ASP.NET using AJAX,LINQ to SQL and some security features for authentication purpose.The Chat will be according to a specific group.I am getting an error after I attempt to login to the Chat page(default.aspx,in my project) , 
the error is :

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tbmsg_tbusr2". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.tbusr", column 'usrcod'.
>   The statement has been terminated."

Note : tbmsg is a table for storing data about messages and tbusr for storing data about users.
The Back end Code for Default.aspx is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Text;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    chatDataContext obj = new chatDataContext();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Welcome:" + Session["usrnam"].ToString();
            Insert_Msg("Just Login:");
            GetLoggedUser();
            Get_Msg();
        }
    }
    private void Insert_Msg(String m)
    {
        tbmsg k = new tbmsg { msgdsc = m, msgdat = DateTime.Now, msgfrmusrcod = Convert.ToInt32(Session["usrcod"]), msgtousrcod = null, msggrpcod = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["grpcod"]) };
        obj.tbmsgs.InsertOnSubmit(k);
        obj.SubmitChanges();
    }
    private void Get_Msg()
    {
        var q = from p in obj.tbmsgs
                where p.msggrpcod == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["grpcod"])
                select p;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var t in q)
        {
            sb.Append(t.msgdsc + ":" + t.msgdat.ToString() + ":" + t.tbusr.usrnam + "<br/>");
        }
        ltmsg.Text = sb.ToString();


    }
    private void GetLoggedUser()
    {
        var q = (from p in obj.tblogusrs where p.logusrusrcod == Convert.ToInt32(Session["usrcod"]) select p).SingleOrDefault();
        if (q == null)
        {
            tblogusr x = new tblogusr { logusrusrcod = Convert.ToInt32(Session["usrcod"]), logusrgrpcod = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["grpcod"]) };
            obj.tblogusrs.InsertOnSubmit(x);
            obj.SubmitChanges();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var q1 = from p in obj.tblogusrs where p.logusrgrpcod == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["grpcod"]) select p;
        foreach (var t in q1)
        {
            sb.Append(t.tbusr.usrnam + "<br/>");
        }
        ltuser.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            Insert_Msg(TextBox1.Text);
            TextBox1.Text = String.Empty;
            TextBox1.Focus();
        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var q = (from p in obj.tblogusrs where p.logusrusrcod == Convert.ToInt32(Session["usrcod"]) select p).SingleOrDefault();
        if (q != null)
        {
            obj.tblogusrs.DeleteOnSubmit(q);
            obj.SubmitChanges();
        }
        Insert_Msg("Just Logout:");
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Get_Msg();
        GetLoggedUser();
    }
}
```

The HTML Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
           <title></title>
           <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1
        {
            width: 70%;
            height: 25px;
        }
        .auto-style2
        {
            height: 25px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 286px; width: 849px">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <table border="5" style="width: 100%; margin-right: 0px">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30%" class="auto-style2">
                            <asp:Literal ID="ltuser" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                       <td class="auto-style1">
                           <asp:Literal ID="ltmsg" runat="server" />
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                &nbsp;
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Send" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Logout" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Description for tbusr table:

```
usrcod     int   primary key (auto increment)

usrnam     varchar(50)

usrpwd     varchar(50)
```

Description for tbmsg table:

```
msgcod     int   primary key (auto increment)

msgdsc     varchar(100)

msgdat     datetime

msgfrmusrcod   int (foreign key with usrcod of tbusr)

msgtousrcod    int (foreign key with usrcod of tbusr)

msggrpcod      int (foreign key with grpcod of tbgrp)
```

Note : tbgrp is another table for storing data about groups